# Kubernetes Ingress www.example.com gives 404 while https://example.com works

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Does anyone know what could be the problem that i'm getting a 404 when trying to access the website via [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) while https://example.com works without any issues.

Here is the example of my ingress:

```
# Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
# make a new cert
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${APP_NAME}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: 'true'
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: ${APP_NAME}
      port:
        number: 80
  tls:
  - secretName: ${APP_NAME}
    hosts:
    - ${URL}
    - www.${URL}
```

Also I tried to run

```
kubectl describe ingress
```

it returns:

**host:** example.com

Is there an issue with the configuration or why does the www. not redirect properly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the hosts. They need to be specified in `spec.rules`, for example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-virtual-host-ingress-no-third-host
spec:
  rules:
  - host: first.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: second.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
```

> Note: Keep in mind that TLS will not work on the default rule because the certificates would have to be issued for all the possible sub-domains. Therefore, hosts in the tls section need to explicitly match the host in the rules section.

[Source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls)

Comment: since i'm using defaultBackend my understanding is that all the traffic gets forwarded to my only service ${APP_NAME}. So shouldn't it be fine to forward traffic from "www.example.com" as well as https://example.com ?

Comment: @user9468014 : Check this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-redirect-to-www-with-nginx-ingress/) might be helpful to you.